# Set text content dynamically between two component when onDragOver is triggered

Tags: angular, frontend, primeng

I have a problem with a drag&drop function.

I have two component: a timeline and a table.
I would like to drag an element from table component and drop to timeline component. In this case i have to display a blue rectangle which has a textcontent. This textcontent contains the actual time of the timeline when i drag this rectangle.

The problem is i cant modify the textcontent dynamically.

I try to create a service , but it isnt work because onDragOver isn't a lifecycle method. And it's not trigger the DOM changing.

Comment: are you using the DragDropModule from @angular/cdk?

Comment: No . I dont use any module for drag and drop. Should i use ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.